# Object as attribute, get parent class

Tags: php, oop

I've got 2 classes, `Beer` and `Ingredient`.

My class `Beer` got a property called `$ingredients` that is a array of `Ingredient` objects.

If there a way that in my `Ingredient` class I can determine if this object is instanced by *hand*, or belongs to the `$ingredients` property of a `Beer` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "instanced by _hand_"?

Comment: I mean in my code there is this : $ingredient = new Ingredient(2);

Comment: Wait, are there any other methods to create an `Ingredient` other than using the constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No implicit methods. You must notify the instance when that happens.

See this example:

```
class Beer{
    private $ingredients = [];

    public function addIngredient(Ingredient $ing){
        $this->ingredients[] = $ing;
        $ing->setOwner($this);
    }
}

class Ingredient{
    private $owner;

    public function getOwner(){
        return $this->owner;
    }

    public function setOwner($owner){
        $this->owner = $owner;
    }

    public function hasOwner() : bool{
        return isset($this->owner);
   }
}
```

Now you can check if an instance of `Ingredient` is used in a `Beer` using `$ingredient->hasOwner()`.